# Code before a controller's action is executed?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, php, controllers

I would like to write some custom code before any actions in a controller is executed. It would seem like an easy one, but i am unable to find help anywhere in google. I tried to override `preDispatch()` function in my controller, but it ends up getting weird (instead of showing my page, it shows the default page without any content in it)

Its a admin controller and i need to do some custom validation before any action in it is executed. Based on the validation, the request may be forwarded to some other controller.

Answer (score 8):

Good news: there's no need to rewrite preDispatch! There is dynamic eventing that is fired both before and after the dispatch:

An excerpt of what is required to tap into the event in your module's **etc/config.xml** file:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule_capcpv>
                    <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductViewPredispatch</method>
                </yourmodule_capcpv>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
    </events>
</global>
```

And your observer would look like the following:

**app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Observer.php**:

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductViewPredispatch($observer)
    {
        //get the controller action method
        $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        //log something
        Mage::log('Testing - I made it to the predispatch of the catalog product viewAction!');

        //get things from the request:
        $request = $controller->getRequest();

        //set things on the response:
        $reponse = $controller->getResponse();
        $response->setBody('some stuff');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. bt wats the event for before all the actions?

Comment: to run something before *all* actions, use `controller_action_predispatch`

Comment: but won't that be fired before all the actions in every controller? i juz need to execute this for a single controller.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that. You can just use `controller_action_predispatch_` and add the route name, e.g. `catalog` or `customer`.

Comment: thats for all the controllers in a particular module. I checked the `preDispatch()` method in `Varien/Action.php`, dont think there is an option for individual controllers. maybe i'll just use the above event and filter the controller in the observer D:

Comment: That wouldn't be a poor practice, IMHO. It's less invasive than rewriting the controller itself. But, FWIW, I would just add an event handler for each desired action and map to the same class/method.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of Customer->AccountController. In the controller you have override mention mention predispatch function as mentioned below:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
$ExitsopenActions = array(
'create',
'login',
'logoutsuccess',
'forgotpassword',
'forgotpasswordpost',
'changeforgotten',
'resetpassword',
'resetpasswordpost',
'confirm',
'confirmation'
);
$newOpenAction=array('passwordreset');
$allActions=array_merge($ExitsopenActions,$newOpenAction);
$Custompattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $newOpenAction) . ')/i';

if (preg_match($Custompattern, $action)) {
$this->getRequest()->setActionName('create');
}
parent::preDispatch();

if ($action != $this->getRequest()->getActionName())
{
$this->getRequest()->setActionName($action);
}
if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
return;
}
$mypattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $allActions) . ')/i';
if (!preg_match($mypattern, $action)) {
if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
$this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
}
} else {
$this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
}
}
```

**$ExitsopenActions** consists of all the actions that are there in the native.

**$newOpenAction** consists of all the new actions you want to add.